# Can't move a div below in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my code.

I can't move a div (I want to move the green `div.free_space` below the others `div.main_pic` and `div.navigation`. I don't know why. I'm still learning so if you could tell me why this happened I would be grateful. If you see something that is incorrect or something that I can upgrade, tell me!

Thanks

Here is the code:

```css
.main_pic {
    position: absolute;
    height: 600px;
    width: 92%;
    background: black;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Century Gothic, Verdana;
    font-weight: normal;
    left: 4%;
    right: 4%;
    top: 200px;
}
.navigation {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 30%;
    background: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Century Gothic;
    font-weight: normal;
    left: 66%;
    right: 4%;
    top: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.navigation ul {
    text-align: center;
    list-style:none;
}
.navigation li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 2.5%;
}
.navigation li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #999999;
}
.navigation li a:visited {
    color:#4d4d4d;
}
.free_space {
    height: 600px;
    top: 900px;
    width: 100%;
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main_pic"></div>
    <div class="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">ITEM</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ITEM</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ITEM</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ITEM</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="free_space"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use `position: absolute`. It should be reserved to very special use cases. Instead, don't define the `position`tag an use the default behavior. By default, all divs float on top of each other. If you want them to float in a row, use `display: inline-block`. If that still does not give you the control you need, use flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thanks @KonstantinSchubert! I will not use them anymore in the future if I don't know the correct function.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `margin-top` for example:

```
.main_pic{
  margin-top:-200px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 600px;
    width: 92%;
    background: black;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Century Gothic, Verdana;
    font-weight: normal;
    left: 4%;
    right: 4%;
    top: 200px;
}
```

and

```
.free_space {
    margin-top:600px;
    height: 600px;
    top: 900px;
    width: 100%;
    background: green;
}
```

Comment: With your solution the result is not what I want. The black div goes on the top and the navigation div goes below. Not expected this :/

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure about the desired result, but I suppose it's something like in my snippet below. You should use absolute positioning only to position one element on top of another independently of that one's contant. (the parent image then needs `position: relative` in order to function as an anchor for the absolute one). Apart from that, try to position the elements according to their order in the document flow.

```css
.main_pic {
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  width: 92%;
  background: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Century Gothic, Verdana;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.navigation {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 240px;
  right: 0;
  background: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Century Gothic;
  font-weight: normal;
  top: 100px;
}

.navigation ul {
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
}

.navigation li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 2.5%;
}

.navigation li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999999;
}

.navigation li a:visited {
  color: #4d4d4d;
}

.free_space {
  height: 600px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main_pic">
    <div class="navigation">

      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">ITEM</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ITEM</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ITEM</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ITEM</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="free_space"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So I have to add the -position:relative- to the 'free_space' div or not?

Comment: No, only if you want to move it in relation to it's default position in the document flow (i.e. below the others), which is not the case in my snippet

Comment: Look at this page: http://www.ritchieollie.com/home. The free_space div would be the text in the bottom centered horizontally. So now the position of it should be relative if I wanna bring it down?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "bring it down", but if you just want to create some vertical distance between two elements, you can simply add a `margin-top` to the lower one.

Answer (score 0):

Mainly remove `position: absolute;` from `main_pic` class.

```css
.main_pic{
 height: 600px;
 width: 96%;
 background: black;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: Century Gothic, Verdana;
 font-weight: normal;
 left: 4%;
 right: 4%;
 top: 200px;
}
.navigation{
 position: absolute;
 height: 50px;
 width: 30%;
 background: white;
 font-size: 15px;
 font-family: Century Gothic;
 font-weight: normal;
 left: 66%;
 right: 4%;
 top: 100px;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
.navigation ul {
 text-align: center;
 list-style:none;
}
.navigation li {
 display: inline;
 padding: 2.5%;
}
.navigation li a {
 text-decoration:none;
 color: #999999;
}
.navigation li a:visited{
 color:#4d4d4d;
}
.free_space {
 height: 600px;
 top: 900px;
 width: 96%;
 background: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="main_pic"></div>
 <div class="navigation">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">ITEM</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">ITEM</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">ITEM</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">ITEM</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="free_space"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Asshish. I understood the problem!

Answer (score 0):

remove
position: absolute; 
from style.css
.main_pic
i have checked

Comment: Thanks, as other people said it should be a relative element, the only absolute element should be the navigation div. @Arslan Ahmad